# A formula for the general term of series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Consider the following series:

$1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5,\dots$

I am having difficulty coming up with the general term.

Comment: OEIS says: https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C+2%2C+2%2C+3%2C+3%2C+3%2C+4%2C+4%2C+4%2C+4%2C+5%2C+5%2C+5%2C+5%2C+5&language=english&go=Search

Comment: Of course, there's a theorem that says you can have just about any followup term from any finite sequence,  but we won't go into that :)

Answer (score 2):

Since $\sum_{i=1}^n i = \frac{n(n+1)}2$ we know that the starting index of number $n$ is $\frac{n(n-1)}2 + 1 = \frac12(n^2 - n + 2)$ and end index $\frac{n(n+1)}2 = \frac12(n^2 + n)$.
We thus seek a function $f$ such that
$$\left\lfloor f\Big(\frac12(n^2-n+2)\Big)\right\rfloor = \left\lfloor f\Big(\frac12(n^2+n)\Big) \right\rfloor=n$$
for any $n$. Since this grows quadratically, $f$ should be some $\sqrt\cdot$-like function. The "prototype" $f(k) = \sqrt{2 k}$ will give
$$\sqrt{n^2 - n + 2} = \sqrt{(n-\frac12)^2 + \frac74} \quad \sqrt{n^2+n} = \sqrt{(n+\frac12)^2 - \frac14}$$
So aysmptotically, the prototype will assign values $n-\frac12 + \epsilon$ and $n+\frac12 - \epsilon$ to the desired indexes. Adding $\frac12$ before flooring will thus result in $\lfloor n + \epsilon\rfloor = n$ and $\lfloor n + 1 - \epsilon \rfloor = n$. This gives rise to
$$f(n) = \sqrt{2n} + \frac12$$
or
$$a_n = \left\lfloor \sqrt{2n} + \frac12 \right\rfloor$$
in a natural way. What's left is to check that this formula is also okay for small indices $n$, wich it is.

Comment: I could not get this f(k)=sqrt(k/2) thing...\In general, can you tell me if f(n^2)=n, then how do we compute the value of f(n)?

Comment: @inquisitive That was meant to be $\sqrt{2k}$, sorry for the confusion. Do you understand now?

Comment: I am sorry, i still can't understand.  Can you tell me if f(n^2)=n, then how do we compute the value of f(n)? Thanks a lot already.

Comment: @inquisitive Since the inverse of $x^2$ is $\sqrt x$, $f(n) = \sqrt n$.

Comment: OEIS says the formula for a(n) is floor( 1+ sqrt(1+8n)/2). Can you explain how do we get that?

Comment: @inquisitive OEIS says the formula for a different offset is... Precisely that's a formula for $a_{n+1}$ so we compare it to $f(n+1) = \sqrt{2n+2} + \frac12 = \frac12 (\sqrt{4\cdot(2n+2)} + 1) = \frac12(\sqrt{8n + 8} + 1)$. It turns out that the $+8$ term is just as good as a $+1$ term for purposes of flooring.